# Creating Graphical User Interface (GUI) in Python

Tags: python, matlab, user-interface, transition

I work mostly with Matlab but I am little bit familiar with Python as well. I have never created a GUI before, however, I have been suggested to develop a GUI for an important project in Python and not in Matlab.

Considering this situation, are there any suggestions that you would like to give which could help me create GUI in python in a time period of a month? Also, I would like to know if I can use Python's Spyder IDE and create GUI from that platform?

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you look through this list of Python GUI frameworks and choose one based on the needs you have for your application.

http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming

Different frameworks will help you solve different UI related problems. Keep in mind the platform that your app will be used on, as some frameworks are platform specific. I personally have used **WxPython** and **TkInter**, and they are pretty good for basic interfaces. If you are looking for more advanced graphics then **Kivy** might be good to look at.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for the info. The plugin I want to develop will be integrated within another main desktop/offline based software.

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely vouch for wxpython. It's very good for advanced GUI work.